# Assigning data to hash taking longer than expected - Ruby on Rails/Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, hash

Since axlsx can't really handle excel files that contain a large amount of data without having issues, I've decided to build my own for my specific purpose. It generates the spreadsheet with zero issues as far as opening it; however, it takes a lot longer than I expect.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
string_file = "#{tmp_folder}/xl/sharedStrings.xml"
sheet_file = "#{tmp_folder}/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"

col_range = ["A", "B", "C"]

ref_strings = {}
row_num = 2 # Because I have a header row.

strings_template = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(string_file))
main_file = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(sheet_file))

amount_of_strings = strings_template.to_xml.scan("<si>").length # Counts the number of existing strings.

issues = Report.find(1).issues
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(main_file.at_xpath("//*[name()='sheetData']")) do |row|
    Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(strings_template.at_xpath("//*[name()='sst']")) do |xml|
        issues.each do |issue|
            row.row("customHeight" => "1", "ht" => "14.15", "r" => "#{row_num}", "spans" => "1:17", "x14ac:dyDescent" => "0.35") {
            col_range.each do |col|
                col_num = col_range.index(col)
                tmp_string_text = case col_num
                when 0
                    issue.details
                when 1
                    issue.system.ip
                when 2
                    issue.system.dns_name
                end

                if !ref_strings.keys.include? tmp_string_text
                    ref_strings[tmp_string_text] = amount_of_strings
                     string_ref = amount_of_strings             
                     xml.si {
                        xml.t tmp_string_text
                     }
                    amount_of_strings += 1
                else
                    string_ref = ref_strings[tmp_string_text]
                end 

                row.c("r" => "#{col}#{row_num}", "t" => "s") {
                    row.v string_ref
                }
            end
            row_num += 1
            }
        end
    end
end
```

The way Excel adds data to a cell (in its XML format) is by inserting the text into `<si><t>Data here</t></si>` tags within the string_file (in my example), and it builds out the row in sheet_file (in my example) and references this text based on its `<si>` index number. In my example, again, this works fine.

However, I'm noticing that the process takes significantly longer when I un-comment the if condition that adds text to the ref_strings hash. It's checking to see if the text already exists, and if not, it adds something that looks like this {"Here's some random text" => "4"}.

Is there a way I can speed this up while adding text to a hash for reference later? If I simply comment out that one line that adds text to the hash, my 30k rows of data finishes producing the excel spreadsheet in 26 seconds. If I add that back in there, it takes a good 20 minutes (no joke).

Comment: Well, I've found one way to reduce the time by just adding the hash text as opposed to checking if it exists already. I guess as the hash grows larger and larger, the checks to see if it's there already takes longer and longer.

Comment: `ref_strings.key?(tmp_string_text)` would be *much* faster than `ref_strings.keys.include?(tmp_string_text)`. The former is O(1) whereas the latter is O(n).

Comment: Your suggestion is SIGNIFICANTLY faster. I think this makes the whole thing more tolerable now. From 20 minutes to about 1 minute and 40 something seconds. Perfect. Thanks so much!